# ignored a value /BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

site logs table:

```
site    status      timestamp
25224   approved    2022/4/5
25224   pending     2022/4/6
45265   denied      2022/4/5
45265   approved    2022/4/6
```

I have this query, show me the last status of a site.

```
Select 
site,
array_agg(status order by timestamp desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as last_status
From siteLogsTable
```

But, I need to ignored 'pending' values.

result expected:

```
site    last_status
25224   approved
45265   approved
```

Comment: I'm not bigquery expert and don't have a test environment so I'm not going to assume this is definitely the answer, but wouldn't `WHERE status <> 'pending'` do the trick here?

Answer (score 1):

simple group by and filter by where ?

```
select site,last_value over(order by timestamp) as last_status
from siteLogsTable
where status <> 'pending'
group by site
```